# Using SQL Server CE and SQL Server Express

Tags: database, linq, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express, sqlmetal

I have an app which currently uses SQL Server CE, and the schema is in a `.sdf` file. Now we want to allow it to connect to a SQL Server Express edition based on some mode.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Will the Linq-to-SQL files (generated by sql metal) be the same for the both the databases (apart from the name etc)
2. Can we use the linq file generated for `.sdf`, and extend it for the SQL Server Express, and override any DB specific things there? Or is it not advisable to mix both of them ?